# ByteBuffer concatinating without duplicating data

Tags: java, allocation, bytebuffer

I have a list of ByteBuffers whom I want to concat into one big ByteBuffer, without having to allocate the sum of all of theyre bytes.
all the answers ive read here dont really take into account that.
is there an elegant way of doing that?

P.S eventually im turning the resuly ByteBuffer into a string, if theres a way to get straight to the String that would be great aswell..

Comment: What are you going to do with the `String` afterwards? I ask because there may be better alternatives like `JDBC` uses `InputStream`s for example

Comment: the string is for testing purposes only. the main logic I need to overcome is the concatenating the byte buffer without allocating extra memory.

Comment: I see no way, especially given all String init methods take a single char or byte array.

Comment: Why? You should process input as it arrives, not build it all up into one ginormous string.

Comment: I cant that byte[] array im getting is the request header of a packet...
either way your question is not relevant to my needs. I wish you would be less rude and not -1 me because of reasons not related to my question.

Comment: If it can be a `CharSequence` instead of a `String` then you could build one that wraps the `ByteBuffer`s untouched.

Comment: ill look into it. thanks.